# how to import static members of one to another class in the java

Tags: java

I have a doubt about how to import static members of the class to another class.

Project Structure:

[image]

Details.java

```
package JDBC.demo;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Details {
    static ArrayList<Integer>Details=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int number;
    String name;
    Details(int number,String name){
        this.number=number;
        this.name=name;
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
package JDBC.demo;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class Controller {
  @PostMapping("/EnterDetails")
    void insert(@RequestBody Details ob){
    //How to import the static member of the Details class i.e Details (ArrayList)


  }
}
```

Comment: `Details.Details`?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "import"? Do you want to be able to refer to it *inside* of `Controller` as `Details`? Or do you want users of the `Controller` class to be able to say `Controller.Details`? If it's the latter, do you want `Details.Details` and `Controller.Details` to be the *same* array list or two similar looking ones?

Comment: I'm forecasting that you should not do that however as the `Details` is not thread safe and you might observe weird results.

Comment: Finally, the Java convention is to not starts a variable with an uppercase. This way it's easier to identify what is variable versus a class name for instance.

Comment: **Don't.** Static state is almost always a disaster, and this code needs to be entirely redesigned. Perhaps you need some sort of map-backed in-memory repository.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that by Details.Details. But using static is not recommended here. Plus ArrayList is not thread-safe. If you have no option but to use it this way use as the and you

```
  List<String> synlist = Collections.synchronizedList(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have used the `import static ...` and initialize the variable as `static final` in the class which you gotta import. Also, if you are using *Spring Boot* then you have to annotate the class you importing